# Can anyone identify this tri wing twin engine WW1 plane

Tags: aircraft-identification

Can anybody identify this WW1 or earlier plane? This tri-wing plane has two engines, most others I have googled have only one.

[image: Photo from the collection of Corporal W. A. Easman 212580 of the 67th Wing RAF.]

Comment: I see three props... Probably, three engines, two tractor props and one pusher...

Comment: Flying spaghetti monster?

Answer (score 8):

Gianni Caprioni's 1918 Ca 4 triplane bomber, shown here with Caprioni and three companion aircraft. It has a twin boom tail and a pusher prop in the center pod, so it is a triengine triplane.

[image]

[source](https://www.elsevier.com/connect/exploring-world-war-i-through-the-lens-of-a-historic-journal)

Answer (score 3):

Probably a [Caproni Ca.42](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caproni_Ca.4). Six were acquired by the RNAS, which became the RAF in April 1918. (A service number of 2xxxxx indicates a man who transferred in from the RNAS, incidentally, so this fits.)

The squadron which operated these, after renumbering, was No. 227 RAF; [WP suggests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_wings_of_the_Royal_Air_Force) this was part of 67 Wing, though I can't find a clear source for this elsewhere.